# Changing the "placeholder" attribute of HTML5 input elements dynamically using Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

I'm trying to dynamically update the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute of a text field using jQuery.

```
$("textarea").attr("placeholder", "New placeholder text");
```

From Firebug, I can observe that the `placeholder` attribute is indeed changing. But in the rendered `textarea` element, it stays the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do other browsers behave?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using Firebug I can assume you are using Firefox, and Firefox doesn't yet support `placeholder` attribute in the input fields itself.

[Placeholder feature detection](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder)

I just tried on Chrome for Mac and it supports placeholder text on textareas (and changes via javascript)

2015 Update: sometimes I gain reputation for this answer, so I want to clarify that this was accepted as correct because at the time Firefox 3.6 didn't support placeholder attribute. Release 4 then added support ("fixed the issue" wouldn't have been fair) so the code of OP works as expected since then.

Answer (score 51):

try this :

```
$('#inputTextID').attr("placeholder","placeholder text");
```

Answer (score 18):

I think you have to do that :

```
$("textarea").val('');
$("textarea").attr("placeholder", "New placeholder text");
```

Comment: For future visitors this clearning the value first is what did it. Chrome 40.0.2214.93

Comment: Is there a way to set the placeholder text from a var?
ex:
`var $text = 'abc';
$('#id').attr("placeholder", $text);`

Answer (score 3):

```
<label for="myname">Name *</label>
<input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" title="Please enter your name"
       pattern="[A-Za-z ]+, [A-Za-z ]+"
       autofocus required placeholder="Last, First" />
```

Then you want to select the placeholder and replace that text with the `new text that you want to enter`.

```
$("input[placeholder]").attr("placeholder", "This is new text");
```

This will replace the text of `Last, First` to `This is new text`.

Answer (score 2):

working example of dynamic placeholder using Javascript and Jquery
http://jsfiddle.net/ogk2L14n/1/

```
<input type="text" id="textbox">
 <select id="selection" onchange="changeplh()">
     <option>one</option>
     <option>two</option>
     <option>three</option>
    </select>

function changeplh(){
    debugger;
 var sel = document.getElementById("selection");
    var textbx = document.getElementById("textbox");
    var indexe = sel.selectedIndex;

    if(indexe == 0) { 
     $("#textbox").attr("placeholder", "age");

}
       if(indexe == 1) { 
     $("#textbox").attr("placeholder", "name");
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="entername" id="fname"/>
```

JS:

```
$("#fname").attr("placeholder", "New placeholder text");
```