# multiple default values for input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have a search box input field that flashes multiple default values when not in focus. As in *"New York"* for 3 seconds, then *"Los Angeles"* for 3 seconds, etc. or to simulate typing of these would also be nice.

What i have done is this

http://jsfiddle.net/5aD7W/1/

but the problem is that the .val() gets overridden every 3 seconds even when it is in focus.

Comment: Why would you want this? It sounds like a UI feature which is likely to confuse your users.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Damn, I love competitions too much, I did it for him... :(

Comment: @gdoron I know the feeling, you see a really poor question, but you're compelled to find a solution :D

Comment: @Rory McCrossan it is a client request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way That I came up with:

```
var words = ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Home'];
var $search = $('#searchId');
var index = -1;

function foo() {

    if ($search.is(':focus')) {
        return;
    }
    index++;
    $search.val(words[index % words.length]);
}​

setInterval(foo, 3000);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wAKXn/)

Comment: the problem with this is that if i add a $search.val(''); before the return to clear the searchbox, it takes at most the interval time to take effect. if the interval is.. say, 5 seconds, then it's a problem

Comment: @glasspill. I didn't understand what's the problem, tell me how to reproduce it.

Comment: fixed. i added this line  $search.focus(function(){this.value=""});​ at the end to clear the value on focus. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Hed/3/)

In html

```
<input id="txtCity" type="text" value="New York"  />​
```

IN script

```
  arr = ["New York", "Los Angesles", "London"];
txtCity = $('#txtCity');
i=0;
setInterval(function(){ 

    if (txtCity.is(':focus')) 
        return;   
    txtCity.val(arr[i++]);
    if(i==arr.length)
         i = 0;
}, 2000);

$('#txtCity').focus(function(){
    this.value=""
 });
​
​
```

Comment: Couple of things. **1.** You can use the modules operator (`%`). **2.** you don't check about the focus. **3.** You don't need to query the element on every interval, cache it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some scripting to do this, so jQuery is a good way to go. Simple markup won't solve your problem. Related: [Changing the "placeholder" attribute of HTML5 input elements dynamically using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919369/changing-the-placeholder-attribute-of-html5-input-elements-dynamically-using-j)

Comment: Sir, don't get me wrong, but telling the guy that he needs to write code, and a link isn't quite an answer.

Comment: I didn't try to actually solve his problem, but give him a hint how to do so himself. Obviously he has no clue about scripting and providing read-to-copy-and-paste code won't improve his skills in this field. Given the other solutions here, he will ask a question like this again tomorrow.

Comment: Probably true, but you should use a comment if you don't try to solve his problem. Good luck sir!