# Filling input fields with URL

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a registration form for new users and there is a registration code required as part of this form.

Users are sent this code via email, but I would prefer users be able to click a link to go to the form with their unique code.

I start off with a basic form:

```
<form id="form">

  <input class="email" id="fieldEmail" name="email" size="40" type="email" placeholder="Email"><br>

  <input class="username" id="username" name="username" size="40" type="text" placeholder="Username">

   <input class="signup-button" type="submit" value="Signup">

</form>
```

I then add variations of '?#username=text' to the end of my links but this doesn't work - any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/sncj32jo/1/?email=text

Comment: What's your programming language?

Comment: Javascript. Form is HTML and I'm using Jquery as part of the site.

Comment: The `placeholder` attribute is not a substitute for `<label>`, it is an example of what the input should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a simple parameter name in your url like "baseUrl?username=text" and then use jQuery to retrieve the value of parameter 'username' from the URL and use it to set the corresponding form field.

Comment: Thanks! This helped - didn't know I had to use JS to get this to work, I thought it was built into HTML. I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919369/changing-the-placeholder-attribute-of-html5-input-elements-dynamically-using-j as well.