# how to set placeholder default display in bootstrap-daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="form" placeholder="Check In">
```

JS:

```
$('input[name="form"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
});
```

I want to look like this.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx9SE.png)

bootstrap-daterangepicker official website：http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You can do a work-around using this:

```js
$('input[name="from"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
  showDropdowns: true,
});

   $('input[name="from"]').val('');
   $('input[name="from"]').attr("placeholder","Check In");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<input type="text" name="from" placeholder="Check In" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone reading this I believe that this is the correct answer:

```
$('input[name="from"]').val('');
$('input[name="from"]').attr("placeholder","Check In");
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252825

Answer (score 2):

Just add `autoUpdateInput: false` .

```
$('input[name="form"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    autoUpdateInput: false,
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be flagged as solution