# How to add back placeholder after value is emptied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**After clearing textarea's value, the placeholder goes missing. All I need to do is, to add back that placeholder into the textarea.**

> html:

```
<textarea data-reply placeholder="Add your reply" autocomplete="off" name="message" ></textarea>
```

> clear the textarea value

```
$('[data-reply]').val(' ');
```

> adding placeholder (doesn't work)

```
1) $('[data-reply]').attr("placeholder", "New placeholder text");


2) $("textarea[placeholder]").attr("placeholder", "New placeholder text");
```

referred here: [Changing the "placeholder" attribute of HTML5 input elements dynamically using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919369/changing-the-placeholder-attribute-of-html5-input-elements-dynamically-using-j)

Comment: Because you added space character into textarea and placeholder doesn't show when textarea has value. Use `$('[data-reply]').val('')` to clear value of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. Browser will show the placeholder after the value is cleared.

The value you put into textarea is not clearing it. It's a single space character.

```
$('[data-reply]').val(' ');
```

Try:

```
$('[data-reply]').val('');
```